# 502 Bad Gateway - Australia only

Tags: support

I'm getting 502 errors from stackoverflow.com around 3pm AEST at the time of this post. Proxying my traffic through a SFO VPS allows me to access the site.

Accessing https://stackoverflow.com results in an SSL error as the certificate presented is valid only for qa.sockets.stackexchange.com